# NSLayout constraint in subviews of scrollview to arrange them one after another vertically

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, scrollview

I want to add top constraints to the subview of scrollview as the bottom of upper view so that if i animate the upper view the view below it gets stick to the upper view without any other adjustments. Please help.

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: I have tried adding top from the top of the parent i.e. scrollview